# What is the relationship of php-fpm, PHP PDO with ATTR_PRESISTENT and DB transactions

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo

I'm trying to debug some weird locking behavior on my database, and was hoping PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT would help as a short term reduction on connections to our database. Additionally, we have a high connection creation overhead, so I'm trying to reduce this by not opening as many connections (yes- I am aware of things like pgbouncer and it is on our roadmap to get installed).

Let me describe the stack and the problem. First, we are using a load balancer with 3 EC2s in it. Each EC2 is running AMI with pgsql, php-fpm (php 7.2) and nginx. We have a few hundred php-fpm workers per server handling requests. We are using PostGres 10.1

Our code is doing the following to make a DB connection (note: proposed change is to add `ATTR_PERSISTENT`)

```
$db = new \PDO(pgsql:host=host;dbname=dbName,$user,$password,array(\PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true));
```

Now, we have some code that does the following:

```
$db->beginTranscation(); //BEGIN;

$errors = false;
$errors |= $db->updateTableOne($one, $two); // UPDATE table SET one=$one WHERE two=$two;
$errors |= $db->updateTableOne($one, $three); // UPDATE table SET one=$one WHERE two=$three;
$errors |= $db->updateTableOne($one, $four); // UPDATE table SET one=$one WHERE two=$four;
$errors |= $db->updateTableOne($one, $five); // UPDATE table SET one=$one WHERE two=$five;
$errors |= $db->insertFinal($allThings); // INSERT INTO another_table (one,two,three) VALUES (1,2,3),(4,5,6)

if($errors == true) {
    $db->rollback(); // ROLLBACK
} else {
    $db->commit(); // COMMIT
}
```

My core concern is - in the above setup, is it possible that a php-fpm worker will get a request, then halfway through the UPDATEs above (or during the `INSERT`) it will get I/O blocked by the database, and then go process another request. If this can happen, will the `PDO_ATTR_PERSISTENT` use the SAME connection to PostGres as it already had opened (yes hopefully)? If so, is it still in the middle of the other user's transaction? Is there a possibility for collision here where an error in one request will ROLLBACK the prior user's UPDATEs even if there were no issues?

I've read through some docs and I haven't found a clear answer (probably because I'm missing some basics about how the above systems work! Any clarity on how the above would be appreciated!